# How to test different types of test for a single render in React with testing-library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tdd, react-testing-library

I'm new in TDD for the React. I've decided to use the react-testing-library to start TDD for development. Suppose that, I should check a prop and simple text in component:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import Card from '../Card';

test('render without crash', () => {
  render(<Card />);
  expect(screen.getByText('Card Component')).toBeInTheDocument();
});

test('title', () => {
  render(<Card title="test" />);
  expect(screen.getByText('test')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I used `render` two times two check different types of rendering for my component. But I was worry about performance... Is it best practice to separately use `render` in any tests? or I should create something like this common variable:

`const Component = render(<Card title={...} prop2={} prop3={} ... />);`

then use `Component` instead using `render` again?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this would be a bad practice. I usually use one of these approaches :

- render my component once in a beforeEach, and use it in multiple `test()`, if I always need the same setup for each test (props, contexts, redux store...),
- render my component in each `test()`, so I can adjust props and context and test multiple configurations.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61838982/2295549 for a more complete explanation, and some pros/cons.

But using render multiple times is not a bad practice, in fact [it is a pattern used in official docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro/).

Comment: thanks, but i thought it will get more ram + cpu to render complex components... because our components don't limit only in simple UI and it will be complex with details

Comment: It could lead to more RAM/CPU usage, but when it comes to testing strategy I would not worry too much about resources (at least not too early). I would focus on realistic tests, use cases coverage, things that give me confidence, and build a CI server that can handle it.