# How to override render method in RTL?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am writing test with RTL. And i use beforeEach for render function:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  render(<Button {...props} />);
});
```

But what if I need pass special props, how can I override this? If I will just do:

```
const { getByRole } = render(<Button {...props} disabled />);
```

it will throw error that

> Found multiple elements with the role "button"

Also, do I need to clear it after each test, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JEST + React Testing Library: should I render my component with a beforeAll before tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61836925/jest-react-testing-library-should-i-render-my-component-with-a-beforeall-befo)

Comment: @TylerDurden I edited my question, to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

[`rerender`](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#rerender) can do this

> if you'd prefer to update the props of a rendered component in your test, this function can be used to update props of the rendered component.

E.g.

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import React from 'react';

const Button = (props: React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>) => <button {...props}>click me</button>

describe('76118663', () => {
  let rerender: ReturnType<typeof render>['rerender'];
  const props: React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> = { type: 'button' };
  beforeEach(() => {
    rerender = render(<Button {...props} />).rerender;
  });
  test('should override button disabled prop', () => {
    expect(screen.queryByRole('button')).toBeEnabled();
    rerender(<Button {...props} disabled />);
    expect(screen.queryByRole('button')).toBeDisabled();
  });

  test('should override button type prop and reset disabled prop', () => {
    rerender(<Button {...props} type='submit' />);
    expect(screen.queryByRole('button')).toBeEnabled();
    expect(screen.queryByRole('button')).toHaveAttribute('type', 'submit');
  })
})
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76118663/index.test.tsx (6.963 s)
  76118663
    ✓ should override button disabled prop (56 ms)
    ✓ should override button type prop and reset disabled prop (13 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.237 s
```

package version:

```json
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
```